# Strange behaviour with operator[]

Tags: c++

Having spent the last couple of days experimenting with C++ operator[] methods, I've come across an anomaly that I can't easily explain. The code below implements a simple test string class, which allows the user to access single characters via its subscript "operator" method. As I would like to differentiate between lvalue and rvalue subscript contexts, the "operator" method returns an instance of the custom "CReference" class as opposed to a standard C++ character reference. Whilst the "CReference" "operator char()" and "operator=(char)" methods appear to handle each rvalue  and lvalue context respectively, g++ refuses to compile without the presence of an additional "operator=(CReference&)" method as documented below. Whilst the addition of this method appears to placate some kind of compile-time dependency, it is never actually invoked at run-time during the execution of the program.

As someone who thought they had acquired a fundamental understanding of C++ intricacies, this project has certainly proved to be a humbling experience. If anyone could see their way to enlightening me as to what's going on here, I would be eternally grateful. In the meantime, I'm going to have to pull out the C++ books in order to reconcile the void** between what I know and what I think know.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Class for holding a reference to type char, retuned by the "operator[](int)"
// method of class "TestString". Independent methods permit differentiation
// between lvalue and rvalue contexts.
class CReference
{
 private:
   char& m_characterReference;

 public:
   // Construct CReference from char&
   CReference(char& m_initialiser)
     : m_characterReference(m_initialiser) {}

   // Invoked when object is referenced in a rvalue char context.
   operator char()
   {
    return m_characterReference;
   }

   // Invoked when object is referenced in a lvalue char= context.
   char operator=(char c)
   {
    m_characterReference = c;
    return c;
   }

   // NEVER INVOKED, but will not compile without! WHY???
   void operator=(CReference &p_assignator){}
};


// Simple string class which permits the manipulation of single characters
// via its "operator[](int)" method.
class TestString
{
 private:
   char m_content[23];

 public:
   // Construct string with test content.
   TestString()
   {
    strcpy(m_content, "This is a test object.");
   }

   // Return pointer to content.
   operator const char*()
   {
    m_content[22] = 0;
    return m_content;
   }

   // Return reference to indexed character.
   CReference operator[](int index)
   {
    return m_content[index];
   }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 TestString s1;

 // Test both lvalue and rvalue subscript access.
 s1[0] = s1[1]; 

 // Print test string.
 printf("%s\n", (const char*)s1);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question.  However, I would remove the "C" tag, as this is a C++ specific question.

Comment: As for your comment question: why do you have to define the operator= for CReference: Because a struct or class with a reference member variable is not default copyable. Your definition appeases the compiler, but doesn't solve the problem. References are immutable in the sense that they cannot be made to reference something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The line `s1[0] = s1[1];` causes the compiler to generate an implicit copy assignment operator for CReference if you didn't declare one yourself. This causes an error because your class has a reference member, which can't be copied.
2. If you added an assignment operator that takes a parameter of type `const CReference&`, it would get called by the assignment.
3. In your code, you declared a copy assignment operator of type `void operator=(CReference &p_assignator)`. This can't be called because the righthand side of the assignment is a temporary object, which can't be bound to a non-const reference. However, the act of declaring this operator causes the compiler not to try to define an implicit copy assignment operator, and therefore avoids the previous compilation error. Since this operator can't be called, the compiler goes for the other assignment operator that takes a parameter of type `char`.

Comment: Is this all mandated by the standard?  Specifically, the compiler's preference for certain operator overloads?  For reference, VS2010 compiles without complaint...

Comment: Of course, a better solution would be to define `public: CReference& operator=(const CReference& other) { this->operator=(other.m_characterReference); return *this; }`, which implements the reference semantic.  Also, the existing operator should return `CReference&`, in order to detect subsequent use in an r-value context.

Comment: @Oli: VC++ has broken rules for binding references to temporaries.  Here, it results in calling the wrong overload.

Comment: Awesome, precisely the information I was looking for; I would rep you more than x1 if that was possible. Just goes to show that a C programmer cannot expect to tame C++, without first redefining their initial perception of both "const" and references. Cheers mate, this has contributed much to my understanding of C++.

Comment: @Oli: Selection of the correct overload is specified by the section on overload resolution (13.3). Here there is only one overload of the assignment operator which can be called.

Comment: @Oli: The rules are the usual. If the assignment operator is not user defined, it is implicitly declared as `CReference& operator( CReference const & )`, and that is a perfect match for the expression `s1[0] = s1[1];`. When there is a user defined `CReference& operator=( CReference& )` is no longer a match and the compiler has to consider other alternatives, which in this case is `char operator=(char)` together with the implicit conversion `operator char()`. So yes, it is mandated by the standard.

Answer (score 3):

What's happening is that without the definition of `operator=(CReference&)`,there are two possible overloads of `operator=`: the implicitly-defined `operator=(const CReference&)` and your `operator=(char)`.  When it tries to compiled `s1[0] = s1[1]`, it tries to find the best match for `operator=`, which is the implicitly-defined `operator=(const CReference&)`.  But, that isn't allowed to be implicitly-defined, because `CReference` contains a reference member, so you get an error.

Conversely, when you do define `operator=(CReference&)`, there's no longer an implicitly-defined assignment operator.  Sections 12.8 clauses 9-10 of the C++03 standard state:

> 9) A user-declared copy assignment `operator X::operator=` is a non-static non-template member function of class `X` with exactly one parameter of type `X`, `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`.<sup>109)</sup>
>
> 10) If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy assignment operator, one is declared implicitly.
>   The implicitly-declared copy assignment operator for a class `X` will have the form
>
> ```
> X& X::operator=(const X&)
> ```
>
> if
>   — each direct base class `B` of `X` has a copy assignment operator whose parameter is of type `const B&`, `const volatile B&` or `B`, and
>   — for all the nonstatic data members of `X` that are of a class type `M` (or array thereof), each such class type
>   has a copy assignment operator whose parameter is of type `const M&`, `const volatile M&` or
>   `M`.<sup>110)</sup>
>
> Otherwise, the implicitly declared copy assignment operator will have the form
>
> ```
> X& X::operator=(X&)
> ```

So, when it tries to compile `s1[0] = s1[1]`, it has two overload choices: `operator=(CReference&)` and `operator=(char)`.  It choose `operator=(char)` as the better overload because it can't convert a temporary object (the result of `s1[1]`) into a non-const reference.

Comment: Have also repped this answer; I selected interjay's answer over this one, as he used bullet points and I have a short attention span. In conjunction with my preferred answer, the information provided here is invaluable.

Answer (score 1):

I compiled your program on [Ideone](http://www.ideone.com/s3SpC) by removing the overloaded `=` and it gives the following error:

```
prog.cpp: In member function ‘CReference& CReference::operator=(const CReference&)’:
prog.cpp:9: error: non-static reference member ‘char& CReference::m_characterReference’, can't use default assignment operator
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
prog.cpp:70: note: synthesized method ‘CReference& CReference::operator=(const CReference&)’ first required here
```

As the error points out,

```
s1[0] = s1[1];
```

needs the copy assignment operator for `CReference` class.

You have a reference member variable in your `CReference` class

```
char& m_characterReference;
```

For classes with a reference member, you need to provide your own implementation of `=` operator as a default `=` cannot infer what to do with the reference member. So you need to provide your own version of the `=` operator.

So a little bit of speculation here:

With,

```
s1[0]=s1[1]
```

Ideally, for `CReference& CReference::operator=(const CReference&)` to be invoked the argument should be a `const CReference&` but the argument `s1[1]` returns a non constant `CReference&`, so:

1. why does the compiler asks for `CReference& CReference::operator=(const CReference&)` in the code sample link I posted &
2. Why does the error go away if we provide a `=` operator with a non constant argument, like `CReference& CReference::operator=(CReference&)`

As it seems in the absence of an explicit non constant argument copy constructor the compiler does some kind of a optimization and treats the argument of `s1[1]` as an `constant` thus asking for the constant argument copy assignment operator.

If a non constant argument copy assignment operator is explicitly provided the compiler doesn't perform its optimization but just uses the one that is already provided.

Comment: That's not the question, though.  The question is why is a copy-assignment operator needed at all?

Comment: And OP's copy assignment doesn't produce the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a CReference, you can return a char&. That would remove the need for the CReference class, which is dangerous for the reasons that I included in my comment above. You can have two forms of the operator[], one returning char and one returning char&.

Comment: The one that returns a char (the function should be const, by the way) is an rvalue. The one that return char& is an lvalue.

Comment: Note that you could trivially replace references with pointers (internally).

Comment: Those overloads would distinguish based on whether the object is `const` or not, not whether it's an lvalue or an rvalue...

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's see:

```
s1[0] = s1[1];
```

`s1[0]` returns `CReference`
`s1[1]` returns `CReference`

Of course you need an assignment operator that accepts `CReference`.

Hence your statement in bold letters:

```
// NEVER INVOKED, but will not compile without! WHY???
void operator=(CReference &p_assignator){}
```

is incorrect.

Comment: I can confirm that it is never invoked (at least in GCC) - try adding some printf statements.

Comment: The assignment operator is *not* invoked because its parameter is not a const reference. But defining it causes the code to compile - the question is why?

Answer (score 0):

I think your

```
void operator=(CReference &p_assignator){}
```

is invoked since

```
// Test both lvalue and rvalue subscript access.
 s1[0] = s1[1];
```

use the function,  as both s1[0] and s1[1] return `CReference`. and not `char`.

Also you would like to do something like this

```
CReference & operator=(CReference &p_assignator){}
```

to handle

```
s1[0] = s1[1] = s1[2];  //etc...
```

Comment: No, it's not, because the temporary returned from `s1[1]` can't be bound to `p_assignator`.  But it disables the implicit `operator=(const CReference&)` which did match, and forces `operator=(char)` to be called.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: a thought

Why we need to provide user-defined copy assignment operator?
Answer: I think the default behavior of the implicit assignment operator is to re-assign the referenced member variable to refer to another location instead of the semantic in `m_characterReference = p_assignator.m_characterReference;`.  Reference variable for us is a syntactic sugar but for the compiler it is a constant pointer. Thus, the default assignment tries to re-assign this constant pointer.

---

The two functions  `CReference::operator char()` and `CReference::operator=(char)` do not represent *lvalue* and *rvalue*.

As previously mentioned, your main mistake is that you declared the copy assignment operator to return void.  Thus, it won't be invoked.

For the compiler to execute "s[0] = s[1];" and based on your code, first,  s[x] will be converted to CRefernce anonymous objects. Then the compiler search for `operator=()`. Since you provide `operator=(char)`, the compiler is "smart" and try to fulfill this assignment. So, it will invoke operator char() first to convert right-hand side (which CReference(s[1]) to char, then invoke operator=(char) function. The expression (s[0] = s[1]) becomes of type char.

You can avoid this conversion by modifying your code as

```
class CReference
{
private:
  char& m_characterReference;

public:
  // Construct CReference from char&
  CReference(char &m_initialiser)
: m_characterReference(m_initialiser) {}

  char& operator = (const CReference &r) {
  m_characterReference = r.m_characterReference;
  return m_characterReference;
  }
};
```

The assignment operator returns char if you would like to keep the type of "s1[0] = s1[1]" as character.  You should not worry about conversion from char to CReference (in case of s1[0] = s1[1] = s1[2]) since 1-arg constructor will handle this conversion.

A simple and clear example that represents lvalue and rvalue  is

```
class Point {
    public:
        int& x() {return x_value; }
        int& y() {return y_value; }

    private:
        int x_value;
        int y_value;
};

int main()
{
    Point p1;

    p1.x() = 2;
    p1.y() = 4;
    cout << p1.x() << endl;
    cout << p1.y() << endl;
}
```